# Using $pull in mongoDB with nested arrays when using meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

**Outline of problem**

When a user is created a list of pre-defined departments and corresponding categories (which are essentially sub-departments) is associated with their account.

This list of departments and categories is displayed (grouped by department) on the user's /categories page

The user can then add/edit/delete departments and add/delete categories as they see fit.

My problem is that I am unsure of the best way to structure the data initially. Then no matter which way I do it, I run into trouble on the mongoDB queries.

**Problem details**
I have attempted to add the pre-defined department/category data 2 ways when onCreateUser is called and they  add to mongoDB successfully.

(I also looked at putting the info into top level of the user account and user.profile)

1. Into a separate collection

xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
Categories.insert({
          "user": userId,
          "categories": [
      {
         "department": "Kitchen",
         "items": [
            "meat",
            "dairy",
            "fish",
            "dry goods",
            "ACME supplies"
         ]
      },
      {
         "department": "Bar",
         "items": [
            "whiskey",
            "red wine",
            "white wine",
            "champagne & sparkling"
         ]
      }
    ]
    });
```

2. In a separate collection using the following structure:

XXXXXXXXXXXX

```
Categories.insert({
         "user": "userId",
         "categories": [
          {
             "department": "Kitchen",
             "item": "meat"
          },
          {
             "department": "Kitchen",
             "item": "dairy"
          },
          {
             "department": "Kitchen",
             "item": "fish"
          },
          {
             "department": "Kitchen",
             "item": "dry goods"
          },
          {
             "department": "Bar",
             "item": "whiskey"
          },
          {
             "department": "Bar",
             "item": "red wine"
          },
          {
             "department": "Bar",
             "item": "white wine"
          },
          {
             "department": "Bar",
             "item": "champagne & sparkling"
          }
       ]
    });
```

XXXXXXXXXXXX

Using 1. above and the following helper, I can get iterate over the data and group them by department no problem

```
`Template.categoriesPage.helpers({
 getCategories: function(){
      var userId = Meteor.userId();
      var categoriesList = Categories.findOne({
            user: userId
        });
        console.log(categoriesList);
        var categories = categoriesList && categoriesList.categories;

      return categories;

    } 
  });`
```

[image: Department/categories screenshot]

Here is the template:

```
<template name="categoriesPage">
    <div class="ui dividing header">
        <h3 class="ui header">My Categories</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="ui grid">
        {{#each getCategories}}
        <div class="five wide column">
            <table class="ui single line  table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{department}}</th>
                        <th class="right aligned"><span style="color:black" class="label-important label removeDepartment"><i class="remove icon large red"></i></span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {{#each items}}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{this}}</td>
                        <td class="right aligned"><span style="color:black" class="label-important label removeCategory"><i class="remove icon red"></i></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    {{/each}}
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Add Cat.</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    <form class="ui form">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="ui teal button submit"/>
    </form>
</template>
```

Then, I can remove an entire department easily enough (see below). The problem is trying to delete a category - how do I get which department it belongs to and which item it is? I have tried various different ways but with no joy.

```
`Template.categoriesPage.events({
    'click .removeDepartment': function(evt, tmpl) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var userId = Meteor.userId();
        var department = this.department;    
        Meteor.call('removeDepartment', userId, department);
    },
    'click .removeCategory': function(evt, tmpl) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var userId = Meteor.userId();    
     //what code goes here to get appropriate department and item
     // I have tried various different things
      var department = ;
      var item = ;
        Meteor.call('removeCategory', userId, department, item);
    }
    });`
```

Here are my methods on the server:

```
    `removeDepartment: function(userId, department) {
        check(userId, String);
        check(department, String);
        Categories.update({user:userId},{ $pull: { categories: { department:department}}});
        console.log('successfully deleted');
    },
    removeCategory: function(userId, item) {
        check(userId, String);
        check(item, String);
         Categories.update({user:userId, "categories.department":department},{ $pull: { "categories.$.items":item}});
        console.log('successfully deleted');
    }`
```

Would a schema like this work at all?

```
`var kitchenId = Categories.insert({user: userId, department:"kitchen"});
Categories.insert({item:"dairy",parent:kitchenId});
Categories.insert({item:"dry goods",parent:kitchenId});
Categories.insert({item:"meat",parent:kitchenId});
Categories.insert({item:"fish",parent:kitchenId});

var barId = Categories.insert({user: userId, department:"bar"});
Categories.insert({item:"vodka",parent:barId});
Categories.insert({item:"whiskey",parent:barId});
Categories.insert({item:"white wine",parent:barId});
Categories.insert({item:"red wine",parent:barId});`
```

Any advice on best practice would be appreciated. Please bear in mind that I will need to be able to edit the departments and add departments and categories. I will also need to feed the departments and categories into dynamic dropdowns.

Thanks in advance for your help.